# Work with code-created UI-Elements after they were created?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface

I've got a little more theoretical problem I cannot really solve.
It is a Win8 App and written in c#/XAML.

I have a Grid and the user can create multiple TextBlocks within that grid by marking the upper and lower border of that TextBlock.
When the User right-clicks one of his created TextBoxes a menu with a TextBox pops up. That TextBox should enable the user to change the text of the TextBlock.
I have two problems now:

I don't know how to get the text the user enters into that specific TextBlock he right clicked on. One issue there is that the TextBlocks are created anonymously. That means they don't have a name and I don't know how to refer back to that clicked TextBlock.

Another thing I'd like to implement is to enable the user to go to a special mode that allows him to remove his added TextBlocks by simply right-clicking them. I've the same problem of not knowing which TextBlock to remove.

I had a few ideas but they all turned out being nonsense. That is why I won't post any code here for now.

Would you like to give me some hints?

Thank you very much!
FunkyPeanut

This Post is also on
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/653ae428-cc35-417a-b6ed-d9770dcd8d8a/work-with-codecreated-uielements-after-they-were-created?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: Isn't the Textbox sent as `sender` on the rightclick event?

Comment: Yes it is. But still for example if I wanted to remove the TextBlock from the grid the following code won't work:                Grid.Children.Remove(sender as TextBlock);

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code. That's what XAML is for. Use an `ItemsControl` for your items and create a proper ViewModel.